# external monitor issue, when maximizing the screen opens on the laptop

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

i have a fujitsu siemens with ubuntu 14.04 on it, the external screen is a lg 32''. my problem is that when i use the external screen and try to maximize the player to turn on full screen mode, the screen freezes and the fullscreen is relocated on my laptop's screen, anyone knows how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the graphics chipset inside your laptop is simply not capable of displaying moving graphics full screen.  Many people have this problem with laptops which were designed for portability and energy-efficiency as opposed to high speed graphics performance.  When I use such a laptop, I have to choose between either running smaller videos or running them larger at a lower frame-rate.

If you have reason to believe that your laptop is a model which was designed for high performance graphics such as gaming, please list its actual model and when I come back I'll attempt to identify the chipset you probably have.  It may just be a matter of installing the correct drivers for your chips.

Attaching a larger monitor does nothing for slow graphics chips, and their is only a tiny minority of laptops which offer upgrade-able graphics components.  The only ones I've seen were made by Lenovo IBM and were hideously expensive.  It sounds to me like your best bet may be to acquire a marginally gaming-ready Desktop to go with your external Display.

Comment: amilo pi 3540 notebook is the notebook i am using, thanks in advance for the help